# How to show duplicate values in the domain

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a bar chart based on the values that are coming, it should show all the label as it is. The bar chart is grouped in nature.

I am able to create most of it, but somehow value labels are not coming properly.

```
["July 02,2017", "July 09,2017", "July 02,2017", "July 12,2017"]
```

Currently `scale.ordinal` is removing the duplicate values and making scale set like:

```
["July 02,2017", "July 09,2017", "July 12,2017"]
```

Which is disturbing the chart view.

How can I show duplicate values in x-axis as it is?

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kunalvashist/7y8ekcap/3/)

Comment: I'm having trouble picturing what you mean by that -- so each bar chart should have a separate label on the x-axis?

Comment: Yes label should be like "July 02,2017","July 09,2017","July 02,2017","July 12,2017" right now it coming as "July 02,2017","July 09,2017","July 12,2017"

Comment: Ah okay that makes more sense although it would be good to think from a user perspective what this implies but you might have specific reasons for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D3 uses the mathematical concept of [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) and [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)) for the domain and range of the scales. Therefore, domain values should be **unique**.

A workaround in your case is creating another property in your data array, like this, which uses the index of each object to create a property conveniently named `index`:

```
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.index = i
})
```

Then, use that property (which has **unique** values) for the domain of your x scale.

Also, you'll have to change the ticks for the x scale, which you can do with `tickFormat`:

```
.tickFormat(function(d, i) {
    return data[i].Groups
});
```

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wujtnomh/